# "bundle exec rake test" "NoMethodError: undefined method `web_console' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm following along, "Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3rd Edition" by Michael Hartl. I'm in Chapter 3, on the very first attempt to use the test command.

There are two extremely basic pages - home and help - with only text on them. I think the following tests are supposed to check that the pages exist:

`sample_app/test/controllers/static-pages.rb`

```
require 'test_helper'
 class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   test "should get home" do
   get :home
   assert_response :success
 end

 test "should get help" do
   get :help
   assert_response :success
 end
end
```

However, when I run the command

```
$ bundle exec test rake
```

in the terminal window, I receive a long error that begins with

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `web_console' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
```

I've read a variety of suggestions that seem to revolve around gem files, in particular the one for 'web-console.' I've tried moving the gem around a bit to no avail but I'm willing to try it all again. Here is the current gem file:

`sample_app/Gemfile` (comments removed)

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'rails', '4.2.2'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'

gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


gem 'web-console', group: :development

group :development do

  gem 'sqlite3'

  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'spring'

  gem 'guard'

  gem 'guard-minitest'
end


group :test do

  gem 'minitest-reporters'

  gem 'mini_backtrace'



end
```

Here is the entire error code if you're interested:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 6353
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `web_console' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:16:in `<class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:113:in `block in define'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/test_unit/sub_test_task.rb:20:in `invoke_rake_task'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:8:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test:run
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: `bundle exec test rake` - should that be `bundle exec rake test` instead?

Comment: In case you don't realise, you're using an older version of this tutorial.

Comment: @Taryn East, thank you. Yes that is a typo on my question, but I did type it into the terminal correctly.

Comment: Just checking :) It's the sort of silly mistake that can cause endless headaches with a really simple fix... if it were actually the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I may have found an answer: Log off Cloud9. Turn off computer. Restart computer. Log back into Cloud9. Type "bundle exec rake test." And it's fixed. Magic!

On a more serious note, I realize I'm using an older version of the tutorial but the tutorial does direct the student to set up the environment in a way to fit this edition (I believe). Nevertheless, I did see a warning by Cloud9 at some point that the version of Ruby (2.3.0) I was using was "buggy" and to upgrade it to 2.3.1. I don't know if the buggy-ness of Ruby 2.3.0 was the culprit or perhaps buggy-ness in Cloud9, but it's something to be aware of for anyone else using an older version of the Tutorial.